# Duplicate symbols in dynamic library loaded from another dynamic library

Tags: linux, android-ndk, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking, dlopen

I have a situation where I have two shared libraries, let's call them libA.so and libB.so. libA.so gets loaded via dlopen() and uses a singleton. libA.so at some point loads libB.so via dlopen(), which also uses the same singleton. Unfortunately, the dynamic linker cannot merge those tho singleton symbols into one, and the result is two singleton instances.

When such situation happens with an executable and a dynamically loaded library, I know the usual solution is to add -rdynamic when linking the executable. This doesn't work here. The symbol in both libraries is exported as `V` and I don't know what to do to make the dynamic linker merge them together.

EDIT: This was tested on Android and seems to be Android-specific, rather than generic.

Comment: Since both are weak symbols then maybe you need a third `libC.so` that gets loaded first and provides the symbol that both `libA.so` and `libB.so` can bind to.

Comment: This isn't how it is supposed to work, and is not how it works for me. Please provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

> libA.so gets loaded via dlopen() and uses a singleton. libA.so at some point loads libB.so via dlopen(), which also uses the same singleton. Unfortunately, the dynamic linker cannot merge those tho singleton symbols into one, and the result is two singleton instances.

I can reproduce this on a trivial example, but *only if* the loading of `libA.so` uses `RTLD_LOCAL` flag. If I use the `RTLD_GLOBAL`, then a variable shared between `libA.so` and `libB.so` gets resolved to the first loaded instance (inside `libA.so`).

I believe this is working as designed.

Comment: Just made an experiment and, unfortunately, RTLD_GLOBAL doesn't work. I still get two distinct objects in both libraries.

Comment: @krojew Can you make MCVE?

Comment: Yes an no - I have a MCVE, but it's a native android application, so it might not be of any use here.